# Why does division still truncate even though readthedocs.io says it does not?

Tags: solidity

According to readthedocs.io:

> "Division on integer literals used to truncate in earlier versions, but it will 
>   now convert into a rational number, i.e. 5 / 2 is not equal to 2, but to 2.5".

Yet, when I try simple math problems like this on Remix, they are truncated.
So, "5 / 2" still equals 2, and I have to use "%" or "remainder = _dividend - (quotient * _divisor)" to produce the remainder separately.

I believe I am using the latest compiler version "0.4.24".  So is the information from readthedocs just wrong?  Or does it means something else?

Comment: There are no fixed-point numbers in Solidity. See [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83785/24693).

Answer (score 4):

I believe what [that note](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#rational-and-integer-literals) is saying is that this function:

```
function test() public pure returns (uint256) {
    return (5 / 2) * 10;
}
```

used to return 20 but now returns 25.

There are no fixed-point/floating-point numbers in Solidity, so you can't return a number like 2.5, but you can use one up until the point where you try to store it in an integer.

Comment: Ah yes, it is 2; typo.  I edited it.